# how to code a sails http middleware for a directory?

Tags: node.js, http, sails.js, qr-code

i am using one npm package for generating QR code after it will save the image in qr directory and after i cant access the file with my app and also directly. i think it is the problem of middleware.(i can acces the images after sails restating, it is working on my localhost). each time a user using my app it will automatically generate qr for the user changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of ways to do that.

1. Create a symlink in asset (eg: `assets/app`) pointing to your qrcode folder
2. You can access express trough sails.express. So you can add in your `config/bootstrap` :

   `var express = require('express');`
   `sails.express.app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/qrcode_folder'));`
3. Custom middleware. Add in your `config/http.js` :

`var express = require('express');`

```
module.exports.express = {
  qrCodeMiddleware: function (app) {
      app.use(express.compress());
      app.use('/qrcode', express.static(process.cwd() + '/my_qrcode_folder'));
    }
};
```

Comment: those there you mentioned are the steps or ways?

Comment: It's 3 differents ways to achieve it. Take the one you want.

Comment: The First one is i am currently using but not working, let me check the others too..

Comment: i cant even lift sails with 2,3 methods,

msg with 2 :
error: Bootstrap encountered an error: (see below)

with 3 :
var express = require('express');

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined

Comment: with 3 :
var express = require('express');
       

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined